# Obtener el Punto Tangente de una Curva

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Tengo el siguiente df (lo adjuntaré en la publicación):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego trazo dos columnas, la llamada Price y la llamada OG. Y ha mostrado algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces quiero obtener el punto tangente (x, y) que optimiza la curva. En la imagen puedo ver que está cerca de la coordenada (80, 0.160), pero ¿Cómo puedo obtener esta coordenada automáticamente, considerando que la curva podría cambiar en el futuro?

¡Gracias de antemano!

Aqui el df en formato .csv:

> ,INCREASE [%],PRICE,INCREASE,QTY,GPS,NNS,OG [%]
> 0,0.0,47.69,0.0,239032932.10219583,11399480531.953718,9649069936.361042, 1,0.1,52.458999999999996,4.769,267545911.79200616,14035190986.69685,11961949944.986732,0.27315694384293565 2,0.2,57.227999999999994,9.538,296058891.48181653,16942858241.721395,14546786753.89384,0.24307636032561325 3,0.30000000000000004,61.997,14.307000000000002,324571871.1716268,20122482297.027348,17403580363.082355,0.21857913428577896 4,0.4,66.76599999999999,19.076,353084850.8614371,23574063152.614704,20532330772.55227,0.198325906714522 5,0.5,71.535,23.845,381597830.5512475,27297600808.483486,23933037982.30361,0.18134997420002735 6,0.6000000000000001,76.304,28.614000000000004,410110810.2410579,31293095264.633682,27605701992.33637,0.16694472549220507 7,0.7000000000000001,81.07300000000001,33.383,438623789.93086815,35560546521.06528,31550322802.650528,0.1545858626459231 8,0.8,85.842,38.152,467136769.6206784,40099954577.778275,35766900413.246086,0.14387833953735796 9,0.9,90.61099999999999,42.921,495649749.3104888,44911319434.7727,40255434824.12307,0.13452003951711053 10,1.0,95.38,47.69,524162729.0002991,49994641092.04852,45015926035.28145,0.12627665505254082 11,1.1,100.149,52.459,552675708.6901095,55349919549.605774,50048374046.72126,0.11896408514089048 12,1.2000000000000002,104.918,57.22800000000001,581188688.3799199,60977154807.444435,55352778858.44248,0.11243592554246645 13,1.3,109.687,61.997,609701668.0697302,66876346865.56449,60929140470.44511,0.10657445172186328 14,1.4000000000000001,114.456,66.766,638214647.7595404,73047495723.96596,66777458882.729126,0.10128402946033532 15,1.5,119.225,71.535,666727627.4493507,79490601382.64883,72897734095.29456,0.09648623602161768 16,1.6,123.994,76.304,695240607.1391611,86205663841.61314,79289966108.14143,0.09211620281895366 17,1.7000000000000002,128.763,81.07300000000001,723753586.8289715,93192683100.85886,85954154921.26971,0.08811984166718287 18,1.8,133.53199999999998,85.842,752266566.5187817,100451659160.38594,92890300534.67935,0.08445171808362244 19,1.9000000000000001,138.301,90.611,780779546.208592,107982592020.19447,100098402948.37045,0.08107340396640193 20,2.0,143.07,95.38,809292525.8984023,115785481680.28442,107578462162.34296,0.07795218934826136

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con optimizar la curva? ¿A la pendiente de la tangente=0 o a qué?¿Por qué sabes que está cerca de esa coordenada? ¿Cómo lo calcularías "manualmente" si tuvieras que hacerlo?

Comment: Justamente al punto de inflexión o "knee point". Si tuviera que hacerlo manualmente tomaría la derivada de la función de la curva que me daría su razón de cambio y la evaluaria cuando x = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

La librería [`kneed`](https://kneed.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) puede ayudarte para obtener el punto de inflexión, debes tener en cuenta que es importante saber si estas buscando un `knee` o un `elbow`, el tipo de curva y la dirección (Te recomiendo leer la documentación, tiene buenos ejemplos para diferentes escenarios)

Cree un `dataframe` con las columnas PRICE y OG de tus datos para simplificar el ejemplo (Archivo sample2.csv)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kneed import KneeLocator, DataGenerator as dg

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df.plot(x='PRICE', y='OG')
df = df.dropna()

kl = KneeLocator(df['PRICE'], df['OG'], curve = 'convex', direction="decreasing")
plt.vlines(kl.elbow, 0.14, 0.28, linestyles="--")
```

Esto devuelve la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica]

Para obtener el valor numérico puedes utilizar el método `knee` o `elbow`, para la coordenada X y `knee_y` o `elbow_y` para la coordenada Y

```
print(kl.elbow, kl.elbow_y)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
66.766 0.1983
```